# How to convert lpc interface to serial on arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino, lpc

As a hardware illiterate software guy trying to do a hardware prototype, will appreciate an answer to this.

One of the hardware components that I need to integrate supports only lpc interface. Is there a way to have it work with arduino? Does the question even make sense? What are my options with this?

I tried doing a bit of research on this, but simply didn't understand anything, nor was there any direct reference to anything that makes this possible.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're talking about Intel's Low Pin Count protocol.

And I guess, you're trying to make a BIOS flasher, aren't you? ;-)

> Is there a way to have it work with arduino?

yes

> Does the question even make sense?

of course

> What are my options with this?

Have a look at [that article](http://www.mike-stirling.com/2010/08/programming-an-lpc-flash-with-an-avr-and-flashrom) and [this thread](http://www.flashrom.org/pipermail/flashrom/2011-March/006027.html)… It shows and gets into some details in how to implement it.

As you say you're a software guy, just consider that you're trying to implement some kind of network procotol stack, starting from the basic building blocks. You need to take care of sending the bits over the pins, take care of the timings, output the start/end stop flags if there are… And then implement a buffer on top of that to parse a byte, and then bytes, etc…

All you need to do that is to follow the sepecification, and plug a few pins on the Arduino.

Well, your question should be closed for lack of research effort, but hence you say you tried but are still lost, I hope my insights will help you come back and ask a real on-topic question with something you actually *tried*.

HTH